# UIButton created runtime in a loop, now I need a specific function depending on the button touched

Tags: uibutton

I am creating some buttons and putting them inside a UIScrollView like this:

```
int i = 0;
    while (i != numberOfButtons ) {
         int updatetY = 160*i;
        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(updatetY, 0, 160, 60);
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:[buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(MYPROBLEM) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [menuScrollView addSubview:button];


        i++;

    }
```

Now I need to build a method to capture which button is being touched, and run a specific bunch of code (see (MYPROBLEM).

Anybody knows what I can do to "trace" which button is being touched and then run a specific function?

something like:

-(void) buttonfunction

{

```
  case ...

      doThis


  case...

      doThat
```

}

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the tag property of the uibutton control. It's a numeric id for the button. You can set a tag on the button based on the i variable in your loop, for instance:

```
button.tag=i;
```

Then in your button's action message, you would simply add the id of the button as a parameter and check its tag like so:

```
-(void) buttonFunction:(id)sender {
  switch (sender.tag)
  {
    //code goes here
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.